# login oracle enterprise manager with a specified user and password

Tags: oracle

I have created a username 'zabbix' with a password '1234' through the following command in oracle:

```
create user zabbix identified by 1234;
grant connect to zabbix;
grant create session to zabbix;
```

when I connect to oracle via command line there is no error:
sqlplus "zabbix as sysdba"
password:1234
sql>
but the problem is that I cannot login into enterpeise manager via my browser with 'zabbix'!!
I only can login with SYS and SYSTEM users!!!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you trying to log in to EM with the `sysdba` role, as an adminsitrator; or as a normal user? [The documentation explains the difference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbcontrol.htm#CIHFCEFF). Incidentally, when you connect to SQL*Plus like that you're actually connecting as `SYS` not the user you specified; check with `select user from dual`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create user zabbix identified by abc;
grant create session,connect to zabbix;
grant select_catalog_role, select any dictionary to zabbix;
```

Select Connect as **normal**

Comment: Excuse me I forgot to accept it, I did it right now, Thanks again.